# Unable to use scrollIntoView correctly because of lazy loaded components

Tags: javascript, ember.js, scroll, lazy-loading

Im having an issue using `.scrollIntoView` which I suspect is due to lazy loaded components. When the page is scrolling down these lazy loaded components are loaded and increase the page height, changing the position of the element I want to scroll into view.

Is there any way to deal with this without changing the way the lazy loaded components are loaded?

The code I'm using is pretty basic

```
this.goToPageElement('#page-anchor', 'center');

goToPageElement(element, position) {
    const target = document.querySelector(element);
    target.scrollIntoView({
      behavior: 'smooth',
      block: position,
    });
  }
```

Comment: when/how is goToPageElement called?

Comment: from a click event `{{on 'click' this. goToPageElement}}`

Comment: Ive dont a bit more digging and changing the behavior from smooth to auto works. Only for block center tho, end and start still have issues with the page position. I really want to keep smooth tho.

Comment: and when you click this different components render? or are you clicking before the page finishes rendering (aka, you're very fast?)

Comment: No, the page has fully loaded when I click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone facing this issue, we solved it by adding static heights to the lazyLoaded component wrapper. For components with variable height I had to choose an average height, and then change heights based on screen size. This is very easily done with Tailwinds one off classes.

```
<LazyLoaded class="h-[400px] lg:h-[250px]">
```